# gcc how to generate debug symbol files .pdb?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, debug-symbols

I tried to find on google how to generate pdb files for application which were compiled using cygwin64, but I was not unable to make it work,
this is how my make file look like:

```
sample: main.c timer.c functions.c gcc -O3 -export-all-symbols="sample.pdb" -march=native $^ -o $@
```

I found that this command "should" generate pdb files after compile: -export-all-symbols="sample.pdb" but it doesnt, what I need to use that cygwin would generate pdb files?

Comment: gcc can't create debug symbols in the PDB format.

Comment: When how i suppose to get debug symbols?

Comment: Add `-g` to your **gcc** command, it will embed debug symbols into the generated executable, which **gdb** can then use.